# How to get min and max from group of similar records

Tags: mysql

I have a set of records with similar label with different prices.

I need to get the min and max and group by each set of labels.

My table structure is like

```
id|label                             |amount|
--|----------------------------------|------|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 25.95|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 15.31|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 23.75|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 31.58|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 12.29|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  |  6.41|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 11.55|
 1|Syndicate Integrated Webservices  | 24.82|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 41.84|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 25.68|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 13.69|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 23.94|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships|  6.24|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 34.96|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 12.40|
 2|Architect Open-Source Partnerships| 21.85|
```

I want to get one record for with min and max price.
So in this example I should get 2 records with min and max price.

Here's what I have so far.

```
select p2.id, p2.label, MIN(p.amount) as low_price, MAX(p.amount) as high_price from prices p 
inner join packages p2 on p.package_id = p2.id
group by p.package_id
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the manual... HINT: MIN() and MAX()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select id, label, min(amount) as min, max(amount) as max from tablename group by id;
```

Comment: I figured it out right when you posted this. Thanks